# HTTP::Request use IPv6 interface

Tags: perl, ipv6, lwp

I have a Linux machine with IPv6 support, local loopback interface: `::1`.

I created a perl script that sends an HTTP request to the local virtual host:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::INET6Glue::INET_is_INET6;
use LWP;

my $user_agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'http://lwt/docs/info.php';
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $response = $user_agent->request($request);
if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;
}
else {
    die($response->status_line);
}
```

info.php file:

```
<?php
print $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

`lwt` alias is written in /etc/hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1       lwt
```

Currently the output is: "127.0.0.1". So, the request is sent via IPv4.

Is it possible to tell Perl to use IPv6 interface instead?

Comment: It should work, provided that `lwt` resolves correctly. How is it provided? DNS? hosts file? Do you have `IO::Socket::IP`, `IO::Socket::INET6`, or both installed?

Comment: @hobbs It's 1 machine: I use loopback interface. lwt is in /etc/hosts file and is written like this: `127.0.0.1  lwt`

Comment: right, so the only address you provided for `lwt` is an IPv4 address, of course it's going to use IPv4. Make the entry for `::1` instead.

Comment: @hobbs Already tried it. It works. Thanks - you can post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make an IPv6 connection, LWP has to find an IPv6 *address* for your hostname. Since the address you're providing via /etc/hosts, 127.0.0.1, is an IPv4 address, this doesn't happen. You need a hosts entry like `::1 lwt` so that the hostname resolves to the IPv6 loopback address instead.